# How to poll a directory in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to poll a directory to check whether new file is added to the directory in ASP.NET web application (C#). If any new file is added I want to read that file.

Can anybody give me an idea how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Normally you would use [the `FileSystemWatcher` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).  However, you have another problem.  A web application isn't really suited for background processes.  You *can* get away with it by using a background task and threading in general, but it's probably not a good idea.  Always assume that your web application is stateless and can be re-started by the server at any time.

Ask yourself:

- What is going to trigger this polling?
- How is the application going to respond to this polling?

A web application is essentially a request/response system.  Thus, any server-side logic (such as the polling) should be triggered by a request.  But once the response is given, what is going to become of the polling?  Suppose you fork off a thread in the web application which will poll in the background.  What is it going to do when it finds something?  There's no request/response interacting with it at that point.

Could this polling perhaps be delegated to another application?  Perhaps a Windows Service?  Then, in response to finding something during the polling, it can modify values in the web application's database.  That way future requests to the web application would see the updated state.

This would more cleanly separate the concerns on an architectural level.

Comment: I use Forms authentication in my ASP.NET web application and I want to monitor a specific folder. The functionality of the application is as follows.
1. The user logs in to the application.
2. The application should keep scanning a folder for any new files (XML) added. The path to the folder is read from the database.
3. When a new file is created in the folder, the application reads the relevant data from the XML file and displays information regarding that file in the form.

Comment: @Vj87: There's the point I'm making right there in your last statement.  When a new file is created, the application displays that data.  In a web application, that doesn't make sense until somebody _requests_ that data.  In which case the polling isn't getting you anything because you're still waiting for a request before you can display anything.

Comment: OK. Now I see what you mean. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `FileSystemWatcher` and create the instance in `Application_Start` event.

Sample code:

```
protected void Application_Start(
    Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileSystemWatcher fsw =
        new FileSystemWatcher(
        Server.MapPath( “.” ) );
    Application.Add( “myfsw” , fsw );
    // Add event handlers here
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

Dispose this when application ends.

```
protected void Application_End(
    Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileSystemWatcher fsw =
        (FileSystemWatcher
        )Application[“myfsw”];
    Application.Remove( “myfsw” );
    fsw.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind if doing this: You need to somehow keep track of which files have been processed. If a file is added while the application pool is recycling or otherwise down, the FileSystemWatcher will (of course) not alert you of the file. Just logging the file name might not be enough (what if a newer copy of a file is used to replace the existing copy)...

Answer (score 1):

First after your program loads check the directory content and keep it as a list.After that add a timer. The timer will check the content of the directory and compare the current content with the last logged content. After comparing you can see which files are changed in the directory.

you can change the frequency of the timer based on your needs.

Hope it helps.

edit:

call  GetDirectoryContent(); in your program's onload.

```
 FileInfo[] lastUpdatedFies;
 FileInfo[] temporaryFiles; 
 private void GetDirectoryContent()
 { 
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/mydirectorypath/"); 
    lastUpdatedFies = di.GetFiles(".");
  }

private void GetDirectoryContent()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/mydirectorypath/");
    lastUpdatedFies = di.GetFiles("*.*");

}

protected void tmrDirectory_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/mydirectorypath/");
    temporaryFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*");

    foreach (FileInfo f in lastUpdatedFies)
    { 
        //compare the list of files and do whatever you want.
        // you can track any kind of data this way.
    }
}`
```

you can also adjust the timer frequency. In this example i just kept track of files.so you will learn only if a file is deleted or added. if you want to keep track of the file size you can also do it in the same way.

Comment: Can you please give a small code snippet where to initialize the timer and where to insert the loop? 
Thanks.

Comment: i added some uncompleted code . The rest should be trivial. The timer itself is a loop. you just specify the interval and it calls the tick function in that interval.

Comment: @OzgurTmp, where you propose to add this code? Have you noticed, that this is ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Add Filewatcher in global.asmx when the application start event.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, what do you want to do with these files. If you want read these files and cache them for future output, you can use ASP.NET Cache with CacheDependency on specific directory and a callback which will re-read the directory and add new file to cache. You should take a look at [Cache.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc491414.aspx) method and CacheDependency [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3tfwsbfk.aspx)

Comment: I use Forms authentication in my ASP.NET web application and I want to monitor a specific folder. The functionality of the application is as follows. 1. The user logs in to the application. 2. The application should keep scanning a folder for any new files (XML) added. The path to the folder is read from the database. 3. When a new file is created in the folder, the application reads the relevant data from the XML file and displays information regarding that file in the form.

Comment: @Vj87, suppose, the user requested the page after new XML file was added. Do you need to display data only from new file(s) for the moment of previous request or from all files in specified directory?